# How can I comfortably fill a List with new Objects in Groovy?

Tags: java, list, groovy

I want to create a List with 10 different objects of a certain class in Groovy. In Java there is Arrays.fill but I'm certain there is a much more elegant way in Groovy.

I tried this:

```
def mylist = [new MyClass()]*10;
```

But that gives me the same reference for every Item in the List.

Comment: `([Object]*10)*.newInstance()` for the fun of it...

Comment: Have you tried in a chair with slippers? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using @cfrick's version:

```
def l = ([MyClass]*10)*.newInstance()

assert l.size() == 10
assert l.unique().size() == 10
```

It fits on one line and is readable.

Answer (score 1):

You may use simple `withDefault` which returns new object every time it's called:

```
def l = [].withDefault { new Object() }
```

Or (which doesn't make much sense in my opinion):

```
def l = (0..9).collect { new Object() }
assert l.size() == 10
assert l.unique().size() == 10
```

Comment: isn't the second version overcomplicated?  `def l = (0..9).collect{new Object()}`

Comment: Yes, it definitely is ;] Thanks!

Comment: Your first version looks good but you have to iterate over it again to actually create the instances.
Can you elaborate why your second version doesn't make sense? This seems to be the most elegant solution for me.

Comment: It makes sense after @cfrick's suggested correction.

Comment: @unSinn check the first version: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b2293318-31e4-4fa3-9628-7e1496a858a5/view-source ; it created a list with a default for each iteration just to get one key, that is not there

Comment: Ok. I didn't make sense because of: `[].withDefault { new Object() }[it]`. In every iteration an empty list was made `[]`. Got it now? May You accept the answer if it satisfies You?

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously very slow: with your first solution what do you then do? I.e. to create a number x of instances...

Answer (score 0):

A solution using closures to create each object:

```
def create = { new Object() }
objects = ([ create ] * 10)*.call()

assert objects.unique().size() == 10
```